# "No result was found for query although at least one row was expected." Query should display records though in Symfony

Tags: mysql, doctrine, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm trying to retrieve content using two items in the URL. Here is the php/symfony code that should do it:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('ShoutMainBundle:Content');

    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('p.slug > :slug')
        ->andWhere('p.subtocontentid > :parent')
        ->setParameters(array(
                    'slug' => $slug,
                    'parent'  => $page
                ))
        ->getQuery();

    $content = $query->getSingleResult();
```

However, when this code is executed it returns the following error:

> No result was found for query although at least one row was expected.

I have done some tests, and the data held in the `$slug` and `$page` variables hold the correct information. I have also tested the MySQL query and the query brings up the desired result, which confuses me further.

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you want to use "=" instead of ">" ?

Comment: I didn't even notice that! There is a head shape dent in the wall now. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 8):

As it was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227635/no-result-was-found-for-query-although-at-least-one-row-was-expected)

> *You are getting this error because you are using the
>   `getSingleResult()` method. it generates an Exception if it can't find
>   even a single result. you can use the `getOneOrNullResult()` instead
>   to get a NULL if there isn't any result from the query.*
>
> **Query#getSingleResult():** *Retrieves a single object. If the result
>   contains more than one object, an NonUniqueResultException is thrown.
>   If the result contains no objects, an NoResultException is thrown. The
>   pure/mixed distinction does not apply.*

Answer (score 4):

> No result was found for query although at least one row was expected.

Another reason could be:

You did this

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('
                SELECT u FROM MyBundle:User u
                WHERE u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('email', $email);

return $query->getSingleResult();
```

Instead of this

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('
                SELECT u FROM MyBundle:User u
                WHERE u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('email', $email);

$query->setMaxResults(1);

return $query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you've got this message because used

```
$content = $query->getSingleResult();
```

you can just replace it with the row below

```
$content = $query->getOneOrNullResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR) ?? 0;
```

Comment: No, actually I meant SingleScalarResult as a partial case of this problem. I wrote this because I got this page as a result in google search