# No result was found for query although at least one row was expected

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following code:

```
/**
     * Search similar category given a string
     * 
     * @param $searchTerm search similar category
     */
    public function findOneSimilarCategory($searchTerm)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('secondLevelCategory')
                ->select('secondLevelCategory')
                ->where('secondLevelCategory.categoryTitle LIKE :searchTerm')
                ->setParameter('searchTerm', $searchTerm)
                ->getQuery();

        $query->useResultCache(true, self::CACHE_RESULT_LIFETIME, md5(__METHOD__ . serialize('category-search-' . $query->getParameters())));
        $query->useQueryCache(true);
        return $query->getSingleResult();
    }
```

however this gives me an error:

"`PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException' with message 'No result was found for query although at least one row was expected.' in /var/www/Shopious/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php:649`

Comment: Print out the done query and try it in your phpmyadmin, sqlworkbench or whatever.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are using the `getSingleResult()` method. it generates an Exception if it can't find even a single result. you can use the `getOneOrNullResult()` instead to get a NULL if there isn't any result from the query.

***Query#getSingleResult()***: Retrieves a single object. If the result contains more than one object, an NonUniqueResultException is thrown. If the result contains no objects, an NoResultException is thrown. The pure/mixed distinction does not apply.