# APIGILITY + Doctrine: cannot find entities = "No result was found for query although at least one row was expected"

Tags: doctrine, laminas-api-tools

I have a service, doctrine related, completely created by Apigility, with no modifications what so ever. The code was never modified, it works just as Apigility created it.

When requesting a collection:
myapi.local/path

```
{
"count": 25,
"total": 13562,
"collectionTotal": 13562,
"_links":
{ ... more stuff here
},
"_embedded":
{
    "path":
    [
        {
            "pathid": 1,
            "dev": 51729,
            "inode": "2",
            "path": "/disk1",
            "online": true,
            "fileid": "0",
            "_links":
            {
                "self":
                {
                    "href": "http://imageadministration.local/path/1"
                }
            }
        },
        ... and so on
```

When requesting that very same entity myapi.local/path/1:

```
{
    "type": "http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html",
    "title": "Not Found",
    "status": 404,
    "detail": "Entity was not found"
}
```

Response headers:

```
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/problem+json
Date: Fri, 08 Apr 2016 08:40:35 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.17
access-control-allow-origin: *
```

Debuging the code step by step, I could find a "No result was found for query although at least one row was expected". This message is inside a Doctrine object and never gets back to the user. No PHP erros, no exceptions, nothing. Indeed, the registry can be found in the DB with a simple select.

The error message itself is explained in other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227635/no-result-was-found-for-query-although-at-least-one-row-was-expected), but since this service is 100% created by Apigility and the exception ocurs inside the Doctrine module and there is not a single line of code of my own, I don´t even know where to start. Entity has no relations and it was automatically created by Doctrine via orm-module.

Any direction will be much appreciated, czr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: it happened to be a very strange encoding error with üäö. when removed, it went back to normal. Unfortunately is still don´t know why.

Comment: Looks like encoding issue. Are you using UTF8?